# Pictures not appearing on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm implementing a heatmap (using heatmap.js library) on top of the two pictures side by side, but the pictures do not appear on Firefox (they appear for split second before disappearing). However, when I tested it on Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome, the pictures appear fine (although there is a pretty large space on the right side of the screen, but that's another story)

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .heatmap-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        -webkit-transition: .3s ease all;
        -moz-transition: .3s ease all;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .heatmap {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

    }


    .option {
        float:left;
        width:48%;
  height:100%
    }

.pictures::after {
  content:"";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="heatmap-wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div class="heatmap" style="position: absolute;">

            <canvas width="100%" height="100%" class="heatmap-canvas" style="z-index=2; opacity: 0; left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">
            </canvas>
            <div class="pictures" style="width:100%; height:100%; z-index=1;">
                <div class="option">
                    <img src="eat.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%; transform:rotate(90deg)">
                </div>
                <div class="option">
                    <img src="drink.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%; transform:rotate(90deg)">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
.
.
<script>
.
.
.

        var body = document.body;
        var bodyStyle = getComputedStyle(body);
        var hmEl = document.querySelector('.heatmap-wrapper');

        hmEl.style.width = bodyStyle.width;
        hmEl.style.height = bodyStyle.height;

        var hm = document.querySelector('.heatmap');
.
.
.
</script>
.
.
.
</body>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to recreate this problem . Worked for me when i added the following to style

```
 html,body{
    height:100%;
}
```

Also add

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

to solve the "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. " warning in firefox .

Comment: It works for me. Thanks. I just have another question: is it caused by a bug specific to Firefox, or something else?

Comment: forgot to mention @alvin-zachariah

Comment: Not sure whether to call it a bug . I habitually set html and body height to 100%